# How to convert function which returns html to JSX object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

let's say, I have this function

```
const test = () => {
    return (
        <div>this is <b>a test</b> text</div>
    )
}
```

I need to convert it to JSX ojbect:

```
var test = function test() {
   return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      "this is ",
      React.createElement(
         "b",
         null,
         "a test"
      ),
      " text"
   );
};
```

You can see an exapmle [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YAoCUKB8MDeAUAJABO8UAriWOgTPTEQDwAmAlgG7ZQAWbEMfjCYAjbAEM4iKEwD0YqQA8Zs9lzoMMBAL5A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

**What is the best way to implement this functionality?**

Thanks!

Comment: you can add babel compiler to your project

Comment: Can you explain me a little more? How can I add compiler in my project? I use babel with React.

Comment: Best way is to create your project using create-react-app package provided by facebook. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: clarification: your first example is `jsx` not html (React should be in scope). Second is pure react api (creating a react element) not an jsx object